# Using django-simple-captcha, when form is_valid why human = True

Tags: python, django, captcha

From [the doc](http://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html), **Validate the Form** part shows the following:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = CaptchaTestForm(request.POST)

        # Validate the form: the captcha field will automatically
        # check the input
        if form.is_valid():
            human = True
    else:
        form = CaptchaTestForm()

    return render_to_response('template.html',locals())
```

Question: What the code "**human = True**" mean, is it just a explanation or a comment which shows "the captcha that human input is True"?

Answer (score 2):

`"human = True"` means that inside that `if` statement you know the captcha has been successfully filled in. You can change this line for your normal code to save the form.